# A beautiful problem on the Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

I recently solved this beautiful mathematical problem on Pigeonhole Principle from Romania TST 2000.

> Let $S$ be the set of interior points of a sphere in three-dimensional space and let $D$ be the set of interior points of a disc on a plane. For any two points $X,$ and $Y$ in the space, let $d(X, Y)$ denote the distance between them. Determine if there is a function $f: S\rightarrow D$ such that
> $d(A, B)\leq d(f(A), f(B))$ for any two points $A, B\in S.$

What are you initial thoughts on this problem? Do you think there is such a function or there isn't. I have given my solution to this problem below. You can also post a solution if you have another one :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We claim that such a function does not exist. To prove this claim, we will assume that there exists such a function $f$, and arrive at a contradiction.

Suppose that there exists such a function $f: S\rightarrow D,$ then we will consider a cube of side length $a$ that is completely in the sphere.

Fix a random positive integer $n$, we will partition the cube into exactly $n^3$ congruent cubes, such that these identical cubes determine $n^2$ identical squares on each face of the larger cube, and $n$ identical line segments on each edge of the larger cube.

Now, we consider the $(n+1)^3$ points that are the vertices of the $n^3$ identical cubes. Let these points be $S_1, S_2, \cdots, S_{(n+1)^3},$ we know that the distance between any two of these points is at least $\frac{a}{n}.$

Let $D_1, D_2, \cdots, D_{(n+1)^3}$ be the points on the disk $D,$ that the function $f$ maps $S_1, S_2, \cdots,$ and $S_{(n+1)^3}$ to, more specifically, let
$$D_i=f(S_i)$$
for all $i\in{1,2,\cdots,(n+1)^3}.$

Since our function $f$ has the property that, for any two points $A, B\in S,$ $d(A, B)\leq d(f(A), f(B))$ holds. Hence, the pairwise distances between the any of the $D_i$ are at least $\frac{a}{n}.$

This means that we can draw circles around each of those points of radii $\frac{a}{2n}$ such that none of the $(n+1)^3$ circles intersect. Let the radius of the disk $D$ be $r,$ we know that each of these circles is contained in the disk concentric with $D$ of a radius of $r+\frac{a}{2n}.$

[image: Diagram]

All these $(n+1)^3$ circles are non-intersecting, and contained in the larger disk. the sum of their areas is lesser than the area of the larger disk. Hence, for all $n\in\mathbb{N},$ we have
\begin{align*}
& \pi\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)^2(n+1)^3\leq\pi\left(r+\frac{a}{n}\right)^2\\
\Rightarrow & \left(\frac{a}{n}\right)^2(n+1)^3\leq\left(r+\frac{a}{n}\right)^2\\
\Rightarrow & \left(\frac{a^2}{n^2}\right)(n+1)^2(n+1)\leq\left(r+\frac{a}{n}\right)^2\\
\Rightarrow & \left(\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}\right)(n+1)a^2\leq\left(r+\frac{a}{n}\right)^2\\
\Rightarrow & \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^2(n+1)a^2\leq\left(r+\frac{a}{n}\right)^2\\
\Rightarrow & \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2(n+1)a^2\leq\left(r+\frac{a}{n}\right)^2.
\end{align*}

Now we note that as $n$ tends to infinity, the term $\frac{1}{n}$ will tend to $0,$ and hence,
\begin{align*}
1+\frac{1}{n} &\rightarrow 1\\
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 &\rightarrow 1\\
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2(n+1)a^2 &\rightarrow\infty.
\end{align*}
since $n+1\rightarrow\infty.$ Hence, the left side of the inequality tends to infinity, implying that since
$$\Rightarrow\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2(n+1)a^2\leq\left(r+\frac{a}{n}\right)^2,$$
the right side will also tend to infinity. But note that as $n\rightarrow\infty,$
\begin{align*}
\frac{a}{n} &\rightarrow 0\\
\Rightarrow r+\frac{a}{n} &\rightarrow r\\
\Rightarrow \left(r+\frac{a}{n}\right)^2 &\rightarrow r^2.
\end{align*}
which is finite, hence, we have arrived a contradiction, and such a function $f$ does not exist.

Comment: Very nice problem. Thank you for sharing it with everyone, and also posting this amazing solution!

Comment: Very nice! thanks for posting the question/answer combination together.

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation! This was a wonderful Pigeonhole problem.